# Sending an e-mail with body using wso2

Tags: wso2, rhino

I'm new in wso2. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582381/sending-an-simple-e-mail-using-wso2-esb/17698779#17698779) code and It sends email ok, but how can I modify the body of the email? 
The ESB sends emails with subject, but with an empty body and without attachments. I have been looking the information in the wso2 documentation about how set the body of the email, but I did not find nothing.

I tried use a script mediator, like in [this](http://heshans.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/send-html-format-email-from-wso2-esb.html) sample but It gave me the next exception:

```
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Can't find method org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMessageContext.setPayloadXML(). (<Unknown Source>#1)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError(DefaultErrorReporter.java:109)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.reportRuntimeError(Context.java:1030)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.reportRuntimeError(Context.java:1086)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.reportRuntimeError1(Context.java:1049)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:162)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:119)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c4._c0(<Unknown Source>:1)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c4.call(<Unknown Source>)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c4.call(<Unknown Source>)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c4.exec(<Unknown Source>)
    at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:55)
    ... 15 more
```

I'm using wso2 4.7.0. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the following proxy i have parametrized the body. It's working fine for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="MailToTransportSenderBCC"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="emailSubjectToSent"
                   expression="//emailSubject"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="emailMassegeToSent"
                   expression="//emailMassege"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="Subject"
                   expression="get-property('emailSubjectToSent')"
                   scope="transport"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="ContentType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <ns:text xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">$1</ns:text>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('emailMassegeToSent')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="mailto:receiver@gmail.com"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
         <header name="To" action="remove"/>
         <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```